# Searching for plug-in or API call for dynamic titles in recurring events

Tags: api, plugins, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'd like to create a set of recurring events but with a dynamic titles, e.g. for counting gym lessons... Is there a way to do this in Google calendar or is there a free or cheap alternative available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems hard to do without scripting it via the Google Calendar API. You can set up the initial recurring event and then iterate over the sequence of other calendar events for that instance using the following endpoints:

- [Retrieve instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances)
- [Update event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch)

I can't think of any other free services that assist with this off the top of my head.

If you'd like similar functionality across other calendaring systems including Outlook and Exchange without having to re-do the implementation with each of those APIs, you can also check out my company Kloudless's unified Calendar API ([docs](https://developers.kloudless.com/docs/v1/calendar)), which provides an abstraction layer for operations such as the ones above.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I also concluded; too bad such a (quite common or at least useful?) use case is not catered for at all. I guess I'll whip up my first calendar plugin then:) Thanks @vinod